# Подразделы выпадающего меню

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте вообщем есть такое меню

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 200) {
   $('.navbar').addClass('fixed-top');
  } else if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
   $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed-top');
  }
 });
 
 function adjustNav() {
  var winWidth = $(window).width(),
   dropdown = $('.dropdown'),
   dropdownMenu = $('.dropdown-menu');
  
  if (winWidth >= 768) {
   dropdown.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('show')
     .children(dropdownMenu).addClass('show');
   });
   
   dropdown.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('show')
     .children(dropdownMenu).removeClass('show');
   });
  } else {
   dropdown.off('mouseenter mouseleave');
  }
 }
 
 $(window).on('resize', adjustNav);
 
 adjustNav();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster');
  .navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: background 0.6s ease-in;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler .menu-icon-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-1px);
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler .menu-icon-bar:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-sform: translateY(-1px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(45deg);
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler .menu-icon-bar:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(135deg);
  -ms-sform: translateY(-1px) rotate(135deg);
  transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(135deg);
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler.collapsed .menu-icon-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler.collapsed .menu-icon-bar:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(0);
  -ms-sform: translateY(-7px) rotate(0);
  transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(0);
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler.collapsed .menu-icon-bar:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px) rotate(0);
  -ms-sform: translateY(5px) rotate(0);
  transform: translateY(5px) rotate(0);
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #c0ca33;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #c0ca33;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-animation: navbar-animation 0.6s;
  animation: navbar-animation 0.6s;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}
.navbar.fixed-top.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: #c0ca33;
}
.navbar.fixed-top.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link::after {
  background-color: #c0ca33;
}
.content {
  padding: 120px 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  }
  .navbar.fixed-top .navbar-nav {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .banner {
    padding: 0 150px;
  }
  .banner h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
  .banner p {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding: 23px 15px;
  }
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
  }
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::after {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: dropdown-animation 0.3s;
    animation: dropdown-animation 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes navbar-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes navbar-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dropdown-animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    transform: scaleY(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@keyframes dropdown-animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    transform: scaleY(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header-area overlay">

     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
   
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
    <span class="menu-icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="menu-icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="menu-icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   
   <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li><a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">About Us</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 1</a>
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 2</a>
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 3</a>
      </div>
      
     </li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 1</a>
       
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 2</a>
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 3</a>
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 4</a>
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 5</a>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Многие уже наверное заметили что это самое простое dropdown (т е выпадающее) меню. И работает оно отлично. Но в этом меню есть только один уровень. Т е при наведении на ссылку Services  например выпадает ещё один уровень меню и всё. Собственно вопрос. Как можно вставить ещё один уровень выпадающих ссылок из под первого. А точнее например при наведении на Services выпадает список и при наведении например на одну из этих ссылок выпадало ещё один список ...подскажите пожалуйста.

PS : пожалуйста не ругайте сильно за то что  код выполняется неправильно т е отображается криво. На компьютере всё работает а тут не смог поправить

Comment: в сети много примеров, ищи. https://habrahabr.ru/company/mr_gefest/blog/273907/

Comment: https://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/ahBrb это например. На codepen очень много интересно, посмотри на этот сайт